# Creating XML file in python by iterating over a set of values

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have to create an xml file with root name 'structure' and it should consist of various subElements "packets", each of which contains a tree structure of elements. A single packet should look like this:

```
<L2>
        <srcmac>value1</srcmac>
        <dstmac>value2</dstmac>
    </L2>

    <L3>
        <dscp>
            <timetolive>value3</timetolive>
        </dscp>
    </L3>

    <L4>
        <protocol>value4</protocol>
    </L4>
```

Th packet should be iterated 'n' number of times. **It gives some error saying:** *unbound method write() must be called with ElementTree instance (got str instance instead)*

**This is the code I have written:**

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

import pcapy

import sys

from struct import*

def main():

    count=1

    root=et.Element("structure")

        #creating xml layout
    eachpacket=et.SubElement(root,"packet")


    while count<n:  
      child1=et.SubElement(eachpacket,"L2")
      subchild1=et.SubElement(child1,"smac")
      subchild2=et.SubElement(child1,"dmac")

      child2=et.SubElement(eachpacket,"L3")
      sub1=et.SubElement(child2,"sip")      
      sub2=et.SubElement(child2,"dip")    
      sub3=et.SubElement(child2,"dscp")
      s2=et.SubElement(sub3,"timetolive")

      child3=et.SubElement(eachpacket,"L4")
      schild1=et.SubElement(child3,"protocol")
      try:
        count=count+1

        subchild1.text=str(value1)
        subchild2.text=str(value2)
        s2.text=str(value3)
        schild1.text=str(protocol)

      except:       
        break

      else:
        tree=et.ElementTree(root)
        tree.write("FileNew.xml")
        pass

if __name__== "__main__":
       main()
```

Although I got an XML file as output, but the last entry seems to overwrite all the previous entries, and only the last iteration of 'packet' is stored in my generated xml file.

What do I need to modify to get a complete tree a iterations and to rectify the write() error?

Comment: What are the values of x, value1, value2, value3, and protocol? Show all your code.

Comment: @swatchai it actually read a .pcap (packet) file and get source mac,destination mac addresses from it, and using packet.next() it moves to the next packet in the pcap file. I have checked there is no issue with that. However, since I am new to etree concepts as well a python, I am not able to get what I need to do to get the correct output. For now, you can just try to print value1, value2 etc values to every iteration of the "packet" .....can u suggest some way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did some fixes, including style improvements, at your code and replaced your values like protocol to placeholders, since I have neither your libs, nor logic. As far I tested, it solves both issues.

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as et


n = 5
value1 = 'value1'
value2 = 'value2'
value3 = 'value3'
protocol = 'protocol'


def main():
    root = et.Element("structure")

    # creating xml layout
    eachpacket = et.SubElement(root, "packet")

    for count in range(n):
        child1 = et.SubElement(eachpacket, "L2")
        subchild1 = et.SubElement(child1, "smac")
        subchild2 = et.SubElement(child1, "dmac")

        child2 = et.SubElement(eachpacket, "L3")
        sub1 = et.SubElement(child2, "sip")
        sub2 = et.SubElement(child2, "dip")
        sub3 = et.SubElement(child2, "dscp")
        s2 = et.SubElement(sub3, "timetolive")

        child3 = et.SubElement(eachpacket, "L4")
        schild1 = et.SubElement(child3, "protocol")

        subchild1.text = str(value1)
        subchild2.text = str(value2)
        s2.text = str(value3)
        schild1.text = str(protocol)

    et.ElementTree.write(et.ElementTree(root), "FileNew.xml")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```